# laravel 5.6 MethodNotAllowedHttpException validate in login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

I have a problem with my validation in the login method.

Indeed, the problem is when I try to validate (with the `validate` method) my login by entering wrong login (I want to see the error messages) but the problem appears when it tries to redirect me back.

here is the login

view : 
[image]

html :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                    @if ($errors->has('username'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="mdp" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('mot de passe') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="mdp" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('mdp') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="mdp" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('mdp'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mdp') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                            {{ __('se souvenir de moi') }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('Login') }}
                    </button>

                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error :
[image]

the method of login :

```
class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    public function login(Request $request){

       $this->validate($request, [
                    $this->username() => 'required|string|email|max:255',
                    'mdp' => 'required|string|min:6',
                ],$message);

            if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
                return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            }
            if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
                return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            }
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
```

the route :

```
Route::get('/', PATH_CENTRA_UTILISATEUR.'VerificationController@index')->name('verification_index');
Route::post('/verification',PATH_CENTRA_UTILISATEUR.'VerificationController@verifier')->name('verification_verifier');

Auth::routes();
```

And the list of route 
[image]

You can help me, thank you all.

Comment: When it redirects you back it will be with GET. Do you have a GET route defined for that URL?

Comment: Have you included `Auth::routes();` in web.php? And this use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers; trait have ditto code you are using in login controller

Comment: @rahulsm Yes, I added the road

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already mentioned in a Trait.

Please find below code.

```
LoginController.php

<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Http\Repository\RolePermissionRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $chekker)
    {       
        // \Visitor::log();   //log in db visitor ip, geo location, hit counter
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');    
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

```
web.php

Auth::routes();

// please dont add this in any middleware
```

And check in this file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php. => auth method if there are all routes are mentioned or not.

if nothing works. Please clear route cache and conf cache.
in worse case, try restarting your machine.

**EDIT**

Please see sample overriding of login method.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $remember = $request->has('remember');        
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($request->get('user_check') == '' || $request->get('user_check') == null) {
            $checker = user::where("email",$request->email)->first(); 
            if ($checker) {
                //$this->checkInActive($request);
                if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $checker->email, 'password' => $request->get('password'), 'id' => $checker->id] , $remember)) {
                    return redirect('/home');
                } else {
                    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
                }    
            } else {
                return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: I just saw the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` and there are 9 routes so all roads are fine. I will make your override, I'll let you know if it works. you can tell me what's in the `validateLogin ` method